# What exactly is "manipulating an item"

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, combat

I have a player who is playing an animated treasure chest using the eldritch might complete handbook rulings on intelligent items. There is an ability that allows him to possess someone if they "manipulate" him.

In tonight's game he walked up behind someone who really really hated magical items and licked him with his strange wooden chest tongue plyboard thing placing his "mouth" on this npc.

In disgust the person he licked attempted to pry him away, would thus allow him to make a dominate person attempt based on the eldritch might rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's your call, but I'd rule no.**

What exactly constitutes "manipulation" is a judgement call that's down to the DM to make - D&D does not have a precise definition for this. However, the common language definition of the term is to control or operate something, typically in a skilful way.

I personally would argue that the intent of an ability which specifies "manipulating an item" as a trigger requires that the target do more than simply push or pull the item around, otherwise it would simply specify when the target *touches* the item. For a sword, that means picking it up by the handle and wielding it, for instance; for a chest, attempting to lock/unlock or open/close it would be manipulating the chest. On a chest that has carrying handles, I could see an argument to be made if a target were to actually try and pick the chest up by the handles, too. However, in the situation where the chest has basically flung itself at someone and they are simply trying to push it away (or pry an appendage loose from its grasp), I would not consider that to be the target "manipulating" the chest.

I suspect the intended use of the ability is as a trap against those who do not recognise the magical nature of the character/item and try to use it in the manner one normally uses items of that kind; allowing it to be triggered by the active action of the character/item itself seems unfair.